# How to write database value in text file on defined format

Tags: asp.net, reporting, asp.net-3.5

**I read a delimited text file into dataset. i am writing these dataset values line by line in another text file. my C# syntax is :**

```
try
            {
                DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();

                var r = from p in db.Products
                        select p;
                //DataTable TarGetTable;
                //TarGetTable = AddDataToTable();
                String TargetStringFilePath;
                TargetStringFilePath = @"c:\aaa.txt";
                StreamWriter fw = File.CreateText(TargetStringFilePath);

                foreach (Product drPrintRow in r)
                {

                    //drPrintRow[drPrintRow]
                    String str = drPrintRow.CategoryID.ToString();
                    str +=" "+ drPrintRow.Discontinued.ToString();
                    str +=" "+ drPrintRow.ProductID.ToString();
                    str += " "+drPrintRow.ProductName.sToString();
                    fw.WriteLine(str);
                }


                fw.Flush();

                fw.Close();
                //}
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
```

**I want this output in bellow format**

```
                                        CUSTOMERWISE ORDER STATUS REPORT
                                        ================================
 Trading Date : 1-2-2010                                                                           Date :1-2-2010
                                                                                                     Time :15:00:52                    
      HOWLA TYPE               FILL TYPE              MKT TYPE                   ORDER STATUS                     
    --------------     -------------------------     -----------     ---------------------------------------------
    D : DVP            MF   : MinimumFill            P : PUBLIC      AC : ACTIVE       CF : CompletelyFilled      
    N : NORMAL         PF   : Partial Fill           S : SPOT        NA : NOTACTIVE    FR : FilledAndRejected     
    U : UNSPECIFIED    FOK  : FillOrKill             O : ODDLOT      XE : Executed     EX : Expired               
                       AON  : AllOrNone              B : BLOCK       RJ : Rejected     OM : OriginalOrderModified 
                       PFAK : PartialFillAndKill                     DE : Deactivated  PF : PartiallyFilled       
                                                                     DL : Deleted      CR : CrossingReported      
_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
CUSTOMER  |INSTRUMENT| BROKER  | Quantity|B |   PRICE  | BALANCE |HOWLA| EXPIRY   | MKT|FILL|ORDER |  TORN   |  TORN   |
          |          | ORDER   |         |/ |    Tk.   |   QTY   |TYPE | DATE     |TYPE|TYPE|STATUS| PREFIX  | SUFFIX  |
          |          | REFNO   |         |S |          |         |     |          |    |    |      |   NO    |   NO    |
__________|__________|_________|_________|__|__________|_________|_____|__________|____|____|______|_________|_________|
00002     |BSRMSTEEL |109379297|      500|S |   1325.00|        0|  N  |01-02-2010| P  | PF |  CF  |201003201| 41500123|
          |CITYBANK  |109379298|      200|S |    940.00|        0|  N  |01-02-2010| P  | PF |  CF  |201003201|  6300609|
          |POWERGRID |109379303|      500|S |    789.00|        0|  N  |01-02-2010| P  | PF |  CF  |201003201|  6000269|
          |SPCERAMICS|109379306|     5000|S |     93.60|        0|  N  |01-02-2010| P  | PF |  CF  |201003201| 40200627|
          |CITYBANK  |109379439|     2000|S |    912.00|        0|  N  |01-02-2010| P  | PF |  CF  |201003201|  6300918|
00004     |PREMIERBAN|109379645|      550|B |    402.75|        0|  N  |01-02-2010| P  | PF |  CF  |201003201| 32601990|
          |PLFSL     |109379725|      100|B |    660.00|        0|  N  |01-02-2010| P  | PF |  CF  |201003201| 27800430|
          |MAKSONSPIN|109379373|     2000|S |    110.70|        0|  N  |01-02-2010| P  | PF |  CF  |201003201| 41400304|
          |MPETROLEUM|109379654|      100|S |    329.00|      100|  N  |01-02-2010| P  | PF |  AC  |201003201| 36001036|
          |BXPHARMA  |109379867|      200|S |    185.50|      200|  N  |01-02-2010| P  | PF |  AC  |201003201|  9302082|
00011     |PADMAOIL  |109379692|     1000|S |    811.00|        0|  N  |01-02-2010| P  | PF |  CF  |201003201| 15500272|
          |MPETROLEUM|109379989|     1000|S |    324.70|        0|  N  |01-02-2010| P  | PF |  CF  |201003201| 36001454|
          |CONFIDCEM |109380341|      500|S |   1614.75|        0|  N  |01-02-2010| P  | PF |  CF  |201003201|  6500878|
          |          |109380346|      500|S |   1616.00|      240|  N  |01-02-2010| P  | PF |  PF  |201003201|  6500891|
          |          |109380351|      500|S |   1615.00|        0|  N  |01-02-2010| P  | PF |  CF  |201003201|  6500905|
00012     |APEXTANRY |109379064|      100|B |   1373.50|        0|  N  |01-02-2010| P  | PF |  CF  |201003201|  1300042|
          |          |109379154|      100|B |   1365.00|      100|  N  |01-02-2010| P  | PF |  AC  |201003201|  1300127|
          |          |109379328|      100|B |   1385.00|        0|  N  |01-02-2010| P  | PF |  CF  |201003201|  1300301|
          |UNIONCAP  |109379471|      500|B |    143.00|        0|  N  |01-02-2010| P  | PF |  CF  |201003201|  8000591|
          |          |109379535|      500|B |    143.50|        0|  N  |01-02-2010| P  | PF |  CF  |201003201|  8000651|
          |          |109379774|     1000|B |    142.30|        0|  N  |01-02-2010| P  | PF |  CF  |201003201|  8000931|
          |          |109380425|      500|B |    142.00|        0|  N  |01-02-2010| P  | PF |  CF  |201003201|  8001532|
          |PREMIERBAN|109379218|      100|S |    399.00|        0|  N  |01-02-2010| P  | PF |  CF  |201003201| 32600814|
          |SUMITPOWER|109380383|      100|S |   1324.00|        0|  N  |01-02-2010| P  | PF |  CF  |201003201| 28401076|
          |          |109380438|       50|S |   1321.00|        0|  N  |01-02-2010| P  | PF |  CF  |201003201| 28401129|
00013     |APEXTANRY |109379034|      100|B |   1375.00|        0|  N  |01-02-2010| P  | PF |  CF  |201003201|  1300016|
```

**How to write dataset value in  text file in specified format.Is there any existing software that can do that for me.**

I use Northwind database on C# syntax.HOw to write this product table information in above format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest starting with the [string.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(VS.90).aspx) method and check the additional references on the [documentation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(VS.90).aspx) for help in determining the proper custom format strings.

Comment: How add string.Format in my C# syntax to save database value in TextFile.

Comment: @shamim - `string.Format( "{0,-5:00000}     | {1,10}|` ...  should give you a start.

Comment: thanks it's really helpful.hope you see my wanted format in above example,one column named INSTRUMENT contain string .How to format string on that way as on above example.

Comment: Sorry - the second format string should have been `{1,-10}`. I didn't notice it was left aligned as well. Note that if the column value may contain more than 10 characters, you'll need to use `Substring` with a length of the minimum of 10 and the string length: `string.Format( "{0,-10}", s != null ? s.Substring( 0, Math.Min( 10, s.Length )) : s )`

Comment: thanks it's work well. will you please tell me how to set the column name on header in my C# syntax.i want same work as my above example.thaks again for your help.

Comment: @shamim - the simplest way is probably to just print strings that have the proper spacing, but you could also do a combination of `PadLeft` (or `PadRight`) and formatting with alignment as with the data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `string.Format(...)`. This allows you to format many different data types into a defined string format.